# Socket c bytes received but I can't print the String

Tags: c, sockets, printf, recv

I use this code to receive a String from a Java server in a C client.

```
if( recv( to_server_socket, &reply, sizeof( reply ), MSG_WAITALL ) != sizeof( reply ) )
{
    printf( "socket read failed");
    exit( -1 );
}

printf( "got reply: %d\n", ntohl( reply ) );

char buf[512];
ssize_t nbytes=0;
int byte_count;

byte_count = recv(to_server_socket, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n", byte_count);
buf[byte_count] = '\0';

printf("String : %s\n",buf);
```

For example, when the Java server sends this String

> bZzrEcyVEmjmIf

I got this result

> recv()'d 16 bytes of data in buf String :

so I received 16 bytes but the

```
printf("String : %s",buf);
```

don't show me anything.

The server sent this String

> TYvuDbbKALp3scp

I tried this code

```
   int i=0;
    while(i<byte_count){
        printf("String : %c\n",buf[i]);
        i++;  recv()'d 17 bytes of data in buf
```

and for result I have

> String :  String :  String :  String : T String : Y String : v String
>   : u String : D String : b String : b String : K String : A String : L
>   String : p String : 3 String : s String : c String : p

Comment: Try `printf("String : %s\n",buf);`

Comment: please add a hex dump of `buf`

Comment: also: check what charset the server uses

Comment: it don't work. @Amardeep I edited the code and added the server code. Yes it send a number and it's 7 so one byte and the Sting, and i read the number and then the String

Comment: i have the caracters in the buffer but there are some empty bytes in the beginnen, 2 bytes

Comment: Notice that Java `char` type is 2-bytes (unicode iirc) unlike C `char` type is 1 byte. So be certain you are trying to represent the correct characters.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your characters are printable?

Use something like this to see what you received:

```
for (int i = 0; i < byte_count; i++)
{
    printf("%02x ", (unsigned int) buf[i]);    
}
printf("\n");  // flush stdout
```

Comment: recv()'d 13 bytes of data in buf
String : 
00 0b 65 47 34 79 4e 36 44 44 64 4e 34

Comment: Your first received character is `0x00` so it is normal that when you print this as a string you see nothing. The `0x65` is `b` ASCII value so your string is actually shifted by two characters. Your send in Java is probably appending two bytes of information when sending the string.

Comment: `0b` is hex for 11, which happens to be the same length of the remaining bytes.  So the server is likely preceeding the string data with a 16-bit value specifying the length of the string being sent.  Sending a string's length is common practice in binary protocols.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Java is sending a length-prefixed string. The first two bytes correspond to the length field. These two bytes determine how many bytes follow. Here's how I'd serialise and print that:

```
unsigned int str_len = buf[0] * 256 + buf[1];
char *str = buf + 2;
/* printf("%.*s\n", str_len, str); // You could use this,
                                      instead of the following two lines: */
fwrite(str, 1, str_len, stdout);
putchar('\n');
```

A byte with the value `0` denotes the end of a string, in C. This explains why the string pointed to by `buf` appears to be empty. It also explains why any embedded characters in your length-prefixed string that have the value `0` will cause the commented out `printf` in my code to cease printing the string.

It's a character value that doesn't have a well-defined visual representation. This explains why embedded characters in your length-prefixed string will cause `fwrite` to print awkward-looking characters.

Comment: thaks now i can see the Stirng but i don't understand how to do to get it properly in a new String, like this i can only print it

Comment: I don't really work with C, i learned it few years ago :) i use java

Comment: @user2328999 It doesn't seem to me like someone who had learnt C "a few years ago" would be asking how "to get it properly in a new String". Perhaps you meant to ask "How do I create a new array of `char`?" and/or "How do I copy it into a different array of `char`?"... These are different questions to the one you asked here, but I'm confident that you'll learn the answer to them in your quest to learn C (by reading a book, since trial and error or learning by unguided example/copy, paste and modify can be dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

The string being sent contains 14 characters. If the C application receives 16 bytes for it, there are 2 extra bytes. Probably they are placed at the beginning of the buffer and note the length of the string being sent (this is how I would send strings over a TCP socket since message boundaries are not guaranteed to be kept there). And if the first byte is zero, you will surely see nothing.

Try printing out values of all the 16 bytes from the `buf`.

I would also advise to send and parse a length of the string before the actual characters and then read from the socked the appropriate (known) number of bytes, otherwise you risk to get an incomplete string or two concatenated strings.

Answer (score 0):

The stdout stream is buffered, your printf should include `\n` to flush the stream

```
printf("String : %s\n",buf);
```

or

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct _received_data 
{
    unsigned char len_byte1;
    unsigned char len_byte2;
    char *str;
} received_data;
```

Then, once your receive the buffer:

```
received_data *new_buf = (received_data*) buf;
printf( "String = %s", new_buf->str);
```

Note that the buffers that are used in send & recv are meant to carry binary data. If data being transmitted is a string, it needs to be managed (ie., adding '\0' and end of buffer etc).  Also, in this case your Java server is adding length bytes following a protocol (which the client needs to be aware of).